# i don't know why i it does not work, format %d expects

Tags: c

i get the following error:
format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *'
i don't know why it is expecting a int *, can someone please explain it to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{

    int wisselgeld = 70;
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0;

    a = wisselgeld / 200;
    b = (wisselgeld - (a * 200)) / 100;
    c = (wisselgeld - (a * 200) - (b * 100)) / 50;
    d = (wisselgeld - (a * 200) - (b * 100) - (c * 50)) / 20;
    e = (wisselgeld - (a * 200) - (b * 100) - (c * 50) - (d * 20)) / 10;
    f = (wisselgeld - (a * 200) - (b * 100) - (c * 50) - (d * 20) - (e * 10)) / 5;

    printf("%d\n"
       "%d\n"
       "%d\n"
       "%d\n"
       "%d\n"
       "%d\n", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&a` returns a pointer to the variable a. it's not expectiong `int*`, it was given it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - C automatically merges multiline strings like that. It's really neat.

Comment: You don't need & before your int variables.

Comment: @leetibbett The preprocessor concatenates  adjacent string literals.

Comment: @EOF cool I will revise that comment.

Comment: `man printf` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

`&variable` is a memory address. You are using an `int` pointer (`int *`) when it expects an `int`. To pass an `int` as an argument simply use the variable name, for example `a` instead of `&a`.

Answer (score 1):

&(variable) provides the address of a variable. To print values you can directly use the integer variable name.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` and `scanf` expect two different things, which may be contributing to why you are having this error.

`int*` (a pointer to an integer or the address of an integer) is what you get when you take the address of (&) an integer variable. Simply change `&a, &b`, ... to `a, b` ... for a solution. For using the same variable in both input/output though, keep using `&a` in any scanfs, but use `a` in any printfs.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
printf("%d\n"
        "%d\n"
        "%d\n"
        "%d\n"
        "%d\n"
        "%d\n", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
```

`&` symbol means, that you're taking an address of variable. Since the type of variables is `int`, what you get is an `int *`. What you have to write is

```
printf("%d\n"
        "%d\n"
        "%d\n"
        "%d\n"
        "%d\n"
        "%d\n", a, b, c, d, e, f);
```

Answer (score 0):

removing the & symbols works 
thanks for the help

Comment: When you ask a question and get helpful answers instead of posting answer , please select the most relevent answer.